# How to pass $index as a object key in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am facing a problem with angular where i have a dynamic generated object in the form below

```
object:{
    0: [],
    1: []
}
```

This is set in the angular controller so in the html side i want to do this

```
<tr ng-repeat="comapny in companies"> 
  <td ng-repeat="option in object.$index">{{option.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

$index comes from the `tr` ng-repeat that wraps the ng-repeat with $index variable.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have an object like this you can simply access the array by

```
option in object[$parent.$index]
```

You need to use `$parent.$index` because you want to access the `$index` of the first `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

Objects don't have an index... the correct syntax for `ngRepeat` with objects is `(k, v) in obj` - so you can do:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(id, options) in companies"> 
    <td ng-repeat="option in options">{{option.name}}</td>
</tr>
```